# Integrating HTML & Web Browser OLE control got a blank page

Tags: html, browser, ole, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a problem while integrating HTML into my VFP app. 
I attached the simulated form: http://www.foxite.com/uploads/879e1e57-8b72-4ac8-9453-c8839f2d051e.zip

My app loads HTML into the web browser control by clicking a button. It is OK for the first click.
But on the second click, it got blank and resulted only `<HTML></HTML>`.

I tried to add `THISFORM.htmViewer.Refresh`. It seems to be OK, but if you click it repeatedly several times, it sometimes got blank too.

In my real app, it got blank on the second click without `Refresh()`.
With `Refresh()`, it got blank on the third click, and the second click is not working correctly, HTML was appended instead of overwriting the HTML loaded on the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a fix. The problem is the two lines below:

```
THISFORM.htmlviewer.navigate('about:blank')
THISFORM.htmlviewer.Document.Write(m.lcHTML)
```

Instead of that, I wrote the output HTML into a temp file and then load it into the browser. It worked perfectly.

```
lcTempFile = 'path\to\file\content_rendered.html'
STRTOFILE(m.lcHTML, lcTempFile)
THISFORM.htmlviewer.navigate(lcTempFile)
```

Any better fix will be appreciated.